# R#9 File Layout Broken

Tags: stylecop, resharper-9.0

Ok, so i realise the title is a bit of a broad sweeping statement but i cannot get the file layout in R#9 to work at all.

I recently upgraded and noticed that running Cleanup was not ordering everything correctly anymore, after a bit of digging around i got StyleCop upgraded and applied the plugin for stylecop through R#. Still no joy.

A bit more digging round and found an article that provided a file layout [here](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/574094)

After applying this i did start to get some order back to my code files but i still cannot get the methods to order correctly.

My questions is has anyone else encountered this and how did they resolve this issue, i really like R# and Stylecop and i don't want to have to manually order my code files

Comment: Hmm, so learnt something about this, was going through the code file line by line and i had a few resharper disable comments
`// ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute`
since part of the file above was ordered i tried removing the comment and when i ran cleanup the file ordered properly so looks like this is either a bug with R# or Stylecop where it encounters a resharper disable once comment and cannot continue